# Custom Post Types and Posts are mixed

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, database, bbpress, pods-framework

I need help with a problem related with CPT and WP Database.

I have a wordpress install with **bbPress** and a custom post type called **Destinos**. The problem is that when I´m looking for the forums, or the topics in bbpress it displays my posts and my custom post type destinos instead of forums and topics. Also when I check my custom post type **destinos** it displays the normal posts.

I'm using bbPress, WP 4.0 and PODS Framework (last version of each one) to create and manage my custom post types. I can not figure out what the problem is or with what it is related, I checked the database and the post_type is ok, and when I create a new CPT happens exactly the same. In the following link http://postimg.org/image/bz0hyoa69/ you can find several images that helps to understand the problem.

Comment: There is no answer possible without a look at your code.

Comment: What code do you mean, database wp_post table?

Comment: The code that registers and calls the post type.

Comment: I think that the problem is in the administration and I don't know which file contains the code. Do you know it?